# Put content between actionbar and tabs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an application with several views. On one of the views I have ActionBar with several tabs. For all the tabs there is some common data, that I want to show above the tabs. How can this be achieved. Whatever I try the common data is displayed between the tabs, rather than between the action bar and the tabs.
I want to achieve something like [this](http://alicia.mobile9.com/download/as/ios/04/88/488575683/screen1.jpg) image 
There are tabs like "Facts", "Lineup" etc, but there is also commod data - the two teams and the result
PS: I'm using actionbar sherlock since I want the application to run under android 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use non-action bar tabs. Tabs that you add to the actionbar are either added directly below the actionbar, or inside the actionbar on wide screen devices.

You can use the TabPageIndicator from the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library.

This is a view that you can put anywhere in your layout, so your layout would contain your custom content at the top, and then the tabpageindicator below it.